# Date/Time settings in Files

Tags: pantheon-files

Files are displaying the time in 12 hours format (without AM/PM) when I set my language to English and local settings to Croatian. 
For example I just created a file it should display 18:33 or 6:33PM insted it shows 12hrs format. Date is displayed fine. Is this a known bug or is it just me?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are encountering [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1406795) bug. If so please login to launchpad and click *'affects me'*. In the meantime, you can tell files to use 24hr format with *iso* mode:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences date-format iso`

or *locale* if you want to see your timezone appended at the end:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences date-format locale`

You can reset it to the default *informal* formatting with:

`gsettings reset org.pantheon.files.preferences date-format`